# How to split in JtextArea

Tags: java, email, jtextarea

Hello i am trying to Design a GUI for sending Email

i can send email with my java code in comandprompt but when i try to do it with a GUI i can not split my Emails

that is if i write xyz@gmail.com,abc@gmail.com my email doesn't get sent

in the command promt code i used the java split and it worked but in GUI it doesn't work

Can anybody tell me how can i use comma to seperate two entries in JTextArea?

```
if(!c.isEmpty()) {
    String[] ccsplit = c.split(",");
    String[] ccsplit = c.split(",");

    for(int i = 0; i < tosplit.length; i++) {    
        sendToServer("RCPT TO: " + ccsplit[i]);
        receiveFromServer();}
```

this code worked for the comand promt..but now it doesn't work for JTextArea

Comment: have you check if "c" has right value?

Comment: Also you have two times the line: String[] ccsplit = c.split(",") and in for loop use tosplit array. maybe you must edit your question

Comment: Jimmysnn was right about the answer I gave which was more a comment: The only thing I don't understand is: in your code, you used tosplit.length in the for loop. Yet I think you should use ccsplit.length instead. And I think that will solve your problem.

Comment: i changes it to ccsplit.length but it doesn't work in gui

Answer (score 0):

Your code must look like:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
String c = textArea.getText();
if(!c.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println(c); //check the value of c
    String[] ccsplit = c.split(",");

    for(int i = 0; i < ccsplit .length; i++) {    
        sendToServer("RCPT TO: " + ccsplit[i]);
        receiveFromServer();
    }
}
```

if doesn't work maybe you have another "wrong" in your code.